# Error assigning GCP IAM Role for Creating Monitoring Policy

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-monitoring

I am using a service account to create Monitoring Policy in my GCP Project. I am trying to identify the IAM role that's suited for this via this link and narrowing it down to "Cloud Monitoring" - https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#predefined

I have put in the following roles --
roles/monitoring.alertPolicyEditor
roles/monitoring.admin

It doesn't seem to work and throws the following error --

> ERROR: (gcloud.alpha.monitoring.policies.create) User
> [sa-cloud-service-deployer@gcp-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com] does
> not have permission to access projects instance [gcp-project] (or it
> may not exist): The caller does not have permission

When I assign the role - roles/owner. It seems to work. I don't want to assign Owner permission. Can someone help me what could be the appropriate role?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create a Monitoring Policy, you need the permissions `“monitoring.alertPolicies.create”` and `“logging.notificationRules.create”`. You need to grant the user in the IAM section the roles `“Logging Admin”` and `“Monitoring AlertPolicy Editor”`. That is explained in the following [Google Official Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/access-control#lba-permissions).

As you have added `roles/monitoring.alertPolicyEditor` and `roles/monitoring.admin` along with this try adding logging admin and `roles/monitoring.alertPolicyEditor`, `roles/monitoring.notificationChannelEditor`. Then you can create monitoring policies.

You can also add a `browser` role as suggested by John Hanley.

Comment: Thanks for the link Sai. I have added the logging.viewer role. Am getting the same error.

Comment: Add `Logging Admin` role as i can see you have logging viewer but you need `logging.notificationRules.create`  role.

Comment: Awesome, that worked. In that document it said about either 'Viewer' or 'Admin', I went with viewer. Strange why 'Browser' worked and didn't work. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You also need permission to access projects which is managed by `Resource Manager`.

The simplest solution is to add the role `Browser`.

This page has more details on available roles and permissions:

[Resource Manager: Access control for projects with IAM](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/access-control-proj)

Note: you will need more permissions for each of the resources that you intend to monitor.

Comment: Thanks John. I added the 'Browser' permission. It worked the first time. I then tried again and it stopped working. These are the roles it has - roles/browser, roles/monitoring.admin, roles/monitoring.alertPolicyEditor,roles/monitoring.notificationChannelEditor. Am not sure what happened? I tried removing 'Browser' and adding again but no avail. Any help?

Comment: @VKarthik - Usually the error message will indicate the missing permission. What is the new error?

Comment: Same error as listed in the original question. ERROR: (gcloud.alpha.monitoring.policies.create)...caller does not have permission.

Comment: @VKarthik - Double-check what you are configuring. If you added Browser, the error message **must** change.

Comment: Thanks again. Yes, I did double check and it is for the same account. I have added screenshots to the post. The shell script is working with my account and I have owner access.